# jQuery Datatables - save filter settings global

Tags: jquery, datatables, local-storage

i am using Datatables 1.10 and save my filter setting with the "saveState" option into the localStorage. This works really good but now I am looking for a possibility to make the filter settings global.

Wenn I open the url: www.example.com/table/1 and make some filter settings and than go to www.example.com/table/2 the same filter settings should be applied.

Is that possible?

So far I print out the localStorage and can see that datatables creatas a unique storage entry for each url.

Thank you

Comment: I think you should post your solution as an answer and accept it yourself - perhaps helping other people in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, i found a good Solution for that. Datatables itself has good Callbacks for customize the saveState-Option to use it global:

```
 $("#table").dataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "stateSave": true,
    "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
        // save the filter settings without connecting it to a unique url
        localStorage.setItem("dataTables_filterSettings", JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
        // read out the filter settings and apply
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataTables_filterSettings"));
    },
    "ajax": {
        "url": "www.example.com"
    },
    "columns": [
        { ... },
        { ... }
    ]
});
```